# Getting Request failed with status code 403 with axios get

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, get, axios

I have setup my axios like this:

```js
    const agent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    });
```

and sending a get call like this:

```
    let data = await axios.get('https://www.skechers.com/en-us/', {
        httpsAgent: agent
     });
```

but with some urls my request fails with this error:

**Request failed with status code 403**

what would be the possible reason to cause this error. I have tried setting up headers as follow but still getting the error

```js
    let data = await axios.get(url, {
      httpsAgent: agent,
      headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
      }
    });
```

Comment: do you need to send in some credentials to login?

Comment: no its just a simple call to fetch html source of home page of any website. then I filter the data using cheeriojs.

Comment: can you post the entire erro you get

Comment: You'll be having CORS issues and what you are trying to do is to load all the html onto your page, do you want to parse their HTML? I don't see a point for this call

Comment: @EugenSunic yes I do need to parse the html, how do I resolve CORS issue.

Comment: you do it in the backend usig node.js, don't attempt that on the frontend. but then look into some library for parsing html

Comment: @EugenSunic here is error stacktrace: https://imgur.com/pY1YRoP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209441/discussion-between-mian-muhammad-and-eugen-sunic).

Comment: No time ... check CORS on MDN and see how it can be treated.. you could also use a plugin for that but I don't advise it

Comment: sure @EugenSunic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it has something to do with CSRF cookie not being sent when you are using axios. You can consider two approach

- Either use [axios-cookiejar-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support) to add while making the request
- OR use [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) which provides this inbuilt.

so your code will be simply

```
const got = require("got");

(async () => {
  console.log(await got.get("https://www.skechers.com/en-us/"));
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into that.

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly but I really need to understand about CORS and the related stuff.