# would it be possible to make a reddit postlogger bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js, reddit

Ok, so I am using discord.js, and am looking to create a bot which logs posts to a subreddit when they are posted and all that, possibly with like a 30s - 1m delay, based on how fast the API can go. The current logging system sends new posts every 15 minutes iirc, so is it possible to make it so like whenever a post is made on a subreddit, it is send to a select channel on a discord server via bot?

Answer (score 0):

**What I'm using**

For my example I will be a simple discord.js(v12) bot and I am also using Axios(v0.21.1).

**Starting Code**

This is the code I'll be starting this project with:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();

const axios = require('axios').default;

et lastTimestamp = new Date() / 1000;
let latestPosts = [];

////////////////////////////////////////
// THE CODE FROM BELOW WILL BE HERE  //
///////////////////////////////////////

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === '!test') {
        msg.channel.send(latestPosts.map(arr => arr.name).join('\n'));
    }
}); 

bot.login('TOKEN');
```

You can get the data easily, I'll be using Axios for this, the code is as such:

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
axios.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/new.json?limit=25')
```

Once the get command is done we want to do something, and it is a promise so we can just use `.then`

```js
.then(res => {
    for (const post of res.data.data.children.reverse()) {
```

That code looks complex however I'll explain it, basically you are creating a variable called post for every entry that you got from the `axios.get`, the reason it is reversed is so you get the posts in the order they were posted in.

Checking the post is new:

```js
if(new Date(post.data.created_utc * 1000) > lastTimestamp)
```

Now, we're going to push all of the information and time after the above statement is true.

```js
latestPosts.push({ name: post.data.title, url: post.data.permalink});
lastTimestamp = new Date(post.data.created_utc * 1000);
```

If the above example doesn't help, here is the whole code.

https://gist.github.com/LiamTownsley/3444e48e79a0bb14f3339941e8e5d839

Comment: sorry, I don't know the timestamp stuff too well. How would I go about getting and checking that?

Comment: Edited now :) How it helps.

Comment: ok so I got the following error? Not sure exactly what it's saying, I haven't used axios before

Comment: `(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (/home/container/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/home/container/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/container/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)`

Comment: Try it with `got`, read this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/got

Comment: And this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636207/getting-request-failed-with-status-code-403-with-axios-get